# Ubuntu 18.04 - Logout form an user and login to other user only mouse show up

Tags: gnome, login

I have 2 accounts on Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome):
My account (administrator)
Wife account (regular user)
When I logout form an user and login to other only mouse show up. This thing is happening random at first, second or third switch. I did not have this problem with Ubuntu 17.10 (gnome).
I did something wrong or is a bug?
Is any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
Disabling Wayland did the trick

Edit the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

FROM:
`#WaylandEnable=false`

TO:
`WaylandEnable=false`

Comment: I made the change but it does not work even after the restart